# How do I determine which column has been updated?

Tags: sql-server

My table has 90 columns.

How do I determine which column(s) has/have been updated?

By

```
UPDATE(@COLUMN_NAME)
```

[@COLUMN_NAME in CURSOR]

Answer (score 0):

You can determine this by creating a [`TRIGGER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) based on `UPDATE` statements for your table. The [`COLUMNS_UPDATED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) function can then be used inside your `TRIGGER` definition to determine what columns have been updated.

The `COLUMNS_UPDATED` function returns a `VARBINARY` bit pattern that indicates the columns in a table or view that were inserted or updated.

For instance the condition `COLUMNS_UPDATED()&1` is true if the first column was updated. `COLUMNS_UPDATED()&2` is true if the second column was updated. `COLUMNS_UPDATED()&4` is true if the third column was updated, and so on.

You can test whether multiple columns have been updated by combining the bit patterns. For instance the condition `COLUMNS_UPDATED()&3` is true if both columns 1 and 2 were updated. In binary form `0001 | 0010` equals `0011`, the equivalent in decimal form is `1 | 2` equals '3'.

Comment: Column 2 updated:  COLUMNS_UPDATED(): 0x02000000000000000000,     0x02000000000000000000 & 2 -> 0

Comment: @kish I may have misled you by using '0x0001' etc. That's hexadecimal format, not binary format. Apologies. It is best to express your binary form in hexadecimal format.

Comment: @kish if you wish to know if column 2 was updated, use the expression `COLUMNS_UPDATED()&2>0`

Answer (score 0):

Column 2 updated: 
COLUMNS_UPDATED(): 0x02000000000000000000

0x02000000000000000000 & 2 -> 0

SUBSTRING(0x02000000000000000000,1,1): 0x02

0x02 & 1: 1

0x02 & 2: 2

0x02 & 3: 3

?